# "socket hang up" on http.get

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I got the error `socket hang up` when running the following script. But if I changed the host from `www.google.com` to `www.nodejs.org`, everything was working fine. Why?

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
        host: 'www.google.com',
        port: 443,
        path: '/'
};
http.get(options, function(data) {
        console.log('OK');
        data.resume();
}).on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('Error: ' + e.message);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`www.google.com` completely rejects non-HTTPS requests sent to its HTTPS server, and `www.nodejs.org` will not (it will, however, return a HTTP 400 status because you are making a plain HTTP request to a HTTPS server).

To make HTTPS requests, you need to use the `https` module:

```
var http = require('https');
```